# Suggestion's required on organising data in schema free way

Tags: erlang, mnesia, yaws

I wanted check if i plan to use "erlang record" storing ability as schemaless store, what kind of performance impact i would have.

to be more clear:

I need to have table : person, age, gender,{other attributes, Marital status, Number of childeren....}
the information about person may come with varying attributes. for example : if marital status is unmarried, i would not have attribute number of children for correspoding person.

Table Person should have varying number of coloumns. since Mnesia is schema based, was thinking on having table like:

person,age,gender,Attributes where attribute is list of [ key value pair of properties].
is it good idea to have such schema ?

what kind of query optimizations are possible for query like:
fetch all persons with "Number of children=2".

would query response time impact be linear with number of records in table and number of attributes in each attributelist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mnesia might not be the best fit for what you're trying to do.  In principle the columns/record fields are fixed.  Including a key-value list of extra attributes as you describe is commonly done, but it means you can't query efficiently on those extra fields: each query needs to iterate through the entire table, copy each record and check whether it fulfils the criteria.

> would query response time impact be linear with number of records in table and number of attributes in each attributelist ?

Yes.